# Jquery - Contact field interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys I'm trying to create contect filed interaction. When we click on any field that label text should go up.I tried but didn't work and also attched my code for more clarity. Can you guys help me? Thanks:)

```js
$('.form-grid').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.form-grid {
  max-width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.form-grid input,
.form-grid textarea {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

.form-grid label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.form-grid.active label {
  top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-grid">
  <input type="text">
  <label> Name </label>
</div>

<div class="form-grid">
  <input type="email">
  <label> Email </label>
</div>

<div class="form-grid">
  <input type="tel">
  <label> Phone </label>
</div>

<div class="form-grid">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <label> Message </label>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should just use web framework. Here is the example: https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/text-field

Answer (score 3):

That is because the `$(this)` element in your code actually refers to the `div.form-grid` node, which does not have a value attached to it. What you want is to select the nested input/textarea element, i.e. `$(this).find('input, textarea').first().val()`:

```
$('.form-grid').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).find('input, textarea').first().val()) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
$('.form-grid').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).find('input, textarea').first().val()) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.form-grid {
  max-width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.form-grid input,
.form-grid textarea {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

.form-grid label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.form-grid.active label {
  top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-grid">
  <input type="text">
  <label> Name </label>
</div>

<div class="form-grid">
  <input type="email">
  <label> Email </label>
</div>

<div class="form-grid">
  <input type="tel">
  <label> Phone </label>
</div>

<div class="form-grid">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <label> Message </label>
</div>
```

---

However, I would suggest not binding the `keyup` event listener to the wrapping `div.form-grid`. What you can do, is to bind the `input` event listener to the input element inside `div.form-grid`, and then simply toggle the class on the parent element instead:

```js
$('.form-grid input, .form-grid textarea').on('input', function() {
  var $formGrid = $(this).closest('.form-grid');
  if (this.value)
    $formGrid.addClass('active');
  else
    $formGrid.removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.form-grid {
  max-width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.form-grid input,
.form-grid textarea {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

.form-grid label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.form-grid.active label {
  top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-grid">
  <input type="text">
  <label> Name </label>
</div>

<div class="form-grid">
  <input type="email">
  <label> Email </label>
</div>

<div class="form-grid">
  <input type="tel">
  <label> Phone </label>
</div>

<div class="form-grid">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <label> Message </label>
</div>
```

Comment: this is one part of the problem, another is that he wants the label to go up on .click() and he is using .keyup().

Comment: @Coder95 Updated my answer, I forgot you have a `<textarea>` element. I've also suggested a better approach.

Comment: @Coder95 My bad, fixed the code now. Use `$(this).find('input, textarea').first().val()`

Comment: Nothing happening. I don't know why :(

Comment: @Coder95 Check the code demo (both the hidden and the displayed one) in my answer. They work.

Comment: Not adding active class. Not happening interaction.

Comment: @Coder95 I don't know what's happening on your end, because both code snippets work for me. There's an edit button to your comments: you can update your comments within 5 minutes of posting, instead of leaving a new one-liner comment every other second.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, its working fine.

```
$('.form-grid').on("input", function() {
         $('.form-grid').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add class respect to each input for handling lable tag

```
<div class="form-grid">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <label for="text_input"> Message </label>
</div>
```

In script  keyup function

```
  $('label[for="text_input"]').hide()
```

Try it.